# Question regarding spell checking in iphone app

Tags: ios4

I am wanderirng if a spell checker is available for a UItextview in iphone sdk...

Any example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this...

```
[txtView setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes];
[txtView setAutocapitalizationType:UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords];
```